# Connection refused Error with python socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp

I have hardware which has the ability to receive data/commands via ethernet or serial. 
I am doing socket programming in python to send commands to the hardware. Everything works fine, but once I close the socket (it closes successfully) and then when I try to reinit and create the socket in a different program, it throws me CONNECTION REFUSED
The only workaround for now is to remove the ethernet cable from the network switch and plug back in. and then it works and again once socket is closed and then want to reopen it, Connection refused error pops up.

Since the server code is running on proprietary hardware, I don't have access to it. I can only configure the port and ip address of the hardware.

Here is the snapshot  of the program with the error message
[image]
and also the wireshark snapshot
[image]

and when I removed the ethernet wire and reconnected again , it can connect properly 
see this snapshot.. so not sure where is gng wrong

[image]
Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: The error information has clearly told you, your port can't reach, make sure it is opened on your server-side.

Comment: How do I make sure the port 5049 is opened at my server side ?  As i mentioned , as soon as I disconnect the ethernet wire of my hardware from switch nad re-run the same program, it connects.. and I close by sock.close() method as shown

Comment: Is there any other way I can make sure port is opened (or) to forcely close the 5049 port

Comment: try using `netcat` if you run your server on the linux platform, and if you can login into your server, try running `netstate`.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because the server is not running on that ip and or port. 
This error is common. Try check through this:

- Ensure that there are no other identical addresses. This is
  important.
- Make sure that the server is running before booting up the client.
- Make sure the client has access to the server and the server can accept connections.
- Make sure that the maximum connection setting is high enough to allow an ideal amount of connections. If this is not enabled then all
  other connections get booted
- Also when you said that the only way for you to get it to work is to reconnect your Ethernet cable, this is probably because you have a closed connection. You must set a loop so that the connection can be kept open

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Identical addresses as in IP addresses on the same network as the IP is hardcoded , i can change that and see if it helps.   2) When you say server is running ,  my server is on hardware and its always ON , so i m guesisng its ON 3) I did ping the IP address before running the program and have succesful pings  4) I am not sure about this setting at server side .. I don't have access to the server script and I guess this setting and also socket reuability is done at server side.

Comment: What didn't you get? Did you try all these things?  What was the outcome?

Comment: Sorry Joshua... that was the previous one when I saw the partial answer and got confused